# i get certificate error for docker registry , i have no proxy , is my CA certificate currupted?

Tags: docker

docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.

Answer (score 0):

Two cases , I am considering

1) If you have **created your hello-world docker image locally** on your system , then use `docker run hello-world:<tagname>`

2) And , I think this is urs case , you **dont have hello-world docker image locally** , so docker run when executed checks if `hello-world:latest` is there in local **if not then it goes to docker registry which is Docker hub**.

So , you need to create your account on [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/) and need to do docker login ( username and password ) on terminal before docker run after which it will pull any docker image which is not available locally. –